# R terra plot vector error subscript out of bounds and no legend or axes

Tags: r, spatial, shapefile, terra

I import a vector:

```
library(terra)
v <- vect("my file")
plot(v)
```

works fine

```
plot(v,1)
```

returns

```
Error in g[[i]][[j]] : subscript out of bounds
```

and then successfully plots v, 1 as expected, but there are no axes and no legend available, I don't get a legend even when doing things like

```
plot(v,1, plg=list("topleft"))
```

I am not sure where to begin the trouble shooting?

The .shp file doesn't seem broken, I have check validity and fixed geometries in qgis and .. don't know which way to look now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.41
v <- vect( system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra") )

plot(v, 2)
```

or the more expressive

```
plot(v, "NAME_1")
```

---

Later:

With your file (send to me privately) I had the same error. I fixed it in "terra" version 1.6-48 (you can install the development version with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`.

This was caused by empty geometries (polygons). You can see which geometries are empty with `emptyGeoms`

```
emptyGeoms(v)
# [1] 10543 10544 10545 10546 10547 10548 10549 10550 10551 10552 10553 10554
#[13] 10556 10558 10559 10560 10561 10562 10563 10564 10565
```

And you can remove them with `na.omit`

```
nrow(v)
#[1] 12694
vv <- na.omit(v, geom=T)
nrow(vv)
#[1] 12673
```

Comment: thanks, I have terra_1.6-41. I can also follow the example you post, which implies it is an issue with my file, I think. But I still can't figure out how to troubleshoot the issue. The file opens in qgis fine, in r fine.. .just the plot goes bananananas. In my script is edits that include adding extra columns to values(v), maybe that breaks it?

Comment: Perhaps you can share the file with me?